# Make Tor use Unique IP for each instance open

Tags: c++, python, c, perl, tor

How can I get Tor to use a unique IP for each instance of Tor open in C++, Python or Perl? Is there a command to force it to use a unique IP that I can just call using subprocess?

*cheers

Comment: IIRC recent devel versions of Tor are able to automatically assign different Tor circuits to different SOCKS clients.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to connect to ToR's control port and issue certain signals to have it create a new connection.  You might have to manually check what the end IP is.

[This document](https://svn.torproject.org/svn/torctl/trunk/doc/howto.txt) has some example code in Java and Python for interfacing with ToR along with some of the signals and how to use them.  The one you're looking for is probably `NEWNYM`, but it's not brought up in the linked document.  With a little bit of googling, you may be able to find more info on controlling ToR via its control port.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in bash:

```
(echo authenticate '""'; echo signal newnym; echo quit) | nc localhost 9051
```

Use this in PHP:

```
// flush Tor circuit, obtain new IP
$password = '""'; // replace with your Tor password (if any)
exec("(echo authenticate $password; echo signal newnym; echo quit) | nc localhost 9051", $out);
print_r($out);
```